# Cassandra - Indexing on Multiple Columns with Many Unique Values

Tags: java, cassandra, database, nosql

I currently have a column family that I want to index on multiple columns. The schema I am currently thinking of using is:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.cfname (
    row_key uuid,
    ts timestamp,
    some_field_a blob,
    some_field_b blob,
    some_field_c text,
    some_field_d int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((row_key))
);
```

For each field I want to index on I create a DIY index:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.cfname_some_field_<char>_idx (
    some_field_<char> type,
    ts timestamp,
    row_key uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY ((some_field_<char>), ts, row_key)
);
```

The purpose is to support this kind of query:

```
SELECT * FROM index WHERE some_field_<char> = X AND ts >= Y AND ts <= Z;
```

I will in the future also want to support a query with 1-2 more levels of clustering.

Note that values inside of the fields I want to index on are very unique.

If a typical query to the index may return 100-1000000 row_keys and I need to query cfname to retrieve the values of the row_keys, would this schema be inefficient? How would Cassandra perform when querying 100-1000000 one-width rows from cfname?

Some things I have also considered: embedding the row value inside of the index (lots of duplication as many records have 10+ rows and 4+ fields to index on) and clustering by Date in cfname for wider rows (if the 100-1000000 results are typically within a few dates).

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on a similar use case and one thing i would like to change in DIY Index is the primary key.

I think it should be

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.cfname_some_field_<char>_idx (
    row_key uuid,    
    some_field_<char> type,
    ts timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (row_key,some_field_<char>)
);
```

as the first column in compound primary key is the partition key. The reason i used row_key as partition key is so that similar row keys are stored in same partition.

also don't understand why you want to include ts in primary key ?

again you case might dictate using it as part of the primary key.

Thanks

Comment: In my use case, I want to find some type of object within a time range. Timestamp is related to the object, not when I inserted the row.